# 404 on Controller Endpoint Spring while running on customer server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle, tomcat

I'm getting 404 consistently for a Gradle spring project while running on tomcat 8.5.
I created a simple project from https://start.spring.io and imported it into the spring tool suite.

When I run it as spring boot app, I'm able to hit the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/healthCheck` but when I add it to server I created (tomcat 8.5), I'm getting a 404 error on the same endpoint.

This is my simple controller:

```
@RestController
public class HealthCheckController {

    @GetMapping("/healthCheck")
    public String healthCheck() {
        return "API is accessible";
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.5.4'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And this is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PracticeApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PracticeApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(PracticeApplication.class);
      }

}
```

I have changed the server location to use Tomcat Installation and hence am able to hit `http://localhost:8080` and it comes up with tomcat homepage.

Here's my directory structure for reference:

[image]

I'm new to gradle and spring so apologies if its a stupid thing that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Which are the packages of `HealthCheckController` and `PracticeApplication`?

Comment: Package for ```PracticeApplication``` is ```com.demo.practice``` and for ```HealthCheckController``` is ```com.demo.practice.controller```

Comment: Is this generating a WAR file that you then deployed in Tomcat?

Comment: I have actually added a tomcat server 8.5 to my eclipse and added this project to that. And now I'm just right clicking and starting the server. I have also tried to paste the generated jar file during build to ROOT directory for Tomcat and run startup.bat but getting 404 there too.

Comment: Any reason that led you to not want to simply run the generated jar file with the embedded server?

Comment: Just for sake of learning. I’m curious why its not working and how this is different than running it on embedded server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out Apache Tomcat does not take jar files and to run spring boot app on an external tomcat server (non-embedded ones), WAR file is needed to be created.

I added war to my build.gradle and gave it an alias as well

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

war {
    archiveName = 'practice.war'
}
```

After adding the above, I refreshed the Gradle project and restarted the server and then I hit the below endpoint:
`http://localhost:8080/practice/healthCheck`
This is different from how we hit the above endpoint on the embedded server which is:
`http://localhost:8080/healthCheck`

Another way to run this is to go to `build/libs/` and copy the war into ROOT directory, then run `startup.bat` from `apache/bin/`

Comment: I assumed you were creating already a WAR file because I asked that and you didn't say you were not. But it is great that you were able to find a solution. Don't forget to accept your own answer as the correct one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code as follows:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class PracticeApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PracticeApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(PracticeApplication.class, HealthCheckController.class);
    }
}
```

It seems that you need to list all the configuration classes and components in the application.

Still, I guess that overriding the `configure()` method is not necessary in your case, so I would also try:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class PracticeApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PracticeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both the solutions and none worked. Getting the same 404 error on it :(